# Generating html files from xml file

Tags: java, xml, servlets, xml-parsing

I have a web page where the information of all the users are stored and I am storing the information
of the users in a xml file. COnsider the name of the xml file "abc.xml" when the users to open the 
same page say "www.domain.com/abc.html" I neeed to constracut the HTML fetching the data from the xml using 
servlets.

Comment: You asked pretty much the same question 2 days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of possible (clean) approaches:

- deserialize the xml file with [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) or [jaxb](http://jaxb.java.net/), feed the deserialized data to a JSP and generate the HTML server side.
- use [XSLT](http://zvon.org/comp/m/xslt.html) to have the html rendering done client side.

For me there's no "best" choice between those, it depends on your use case and constraints.